# How can I set Cross-Origin in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

I have a task about general-token. Each request comes from an IP, and I have to call `WithOrigins` in each request.

Actually I need an `AddScoped` service in a middleware.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class CustomCorsPolicyProvider: ICorsPolicyProvider {
    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(HttpContext context,string policyName)
{
    // Implement logic to select a policy based on the request
    // For example, you can vary the policy based on the request's origin, headers, etc.

    var corsPolicyBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder()
        .WithOrigins("http://example.com") // Replace with dynamic logic
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();

    return Task.FromResult(corsPolicyBuilder.Build());
} }
```

then

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyProvider, CustomCorsPolicyProvider>();
    // ... other services 
}
```

AND

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ... other configurations

    app.UseCors(); // Use the custom CORS policy provider

    // ... other middleware
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create token and validate request's IP through middleware as scoped service, you would need to create a custom middleware class and register as Scoped.

You can also generate token in Controller method such as login and validate white listed "AllowedOrigin" list in startup.

Approach to generate token and validated IP in a custom middleware should be as,

```
      public class YourMiddleware : IMiddleware
        {
            private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        
            public YourMiddleware(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                _configuration = configuration;
            }
        
            public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
            {
                var ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
        
                // Check if IP Whitelisted
                var allowedIPs = _configuration.GetSection("WithOrigins").Get<string[]>();
                if(!allowedIPs.Contains(ipAddress))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; 
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Your IP : {ipAddress} not whitelisted");
                    return;
                }
        
                // Get token and add in response header, create a method "CreateJwtToken()" to create token.
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", CreateJwtToken());
        
                await next(context);
            }
        
         }
```

In startup.cs add and use this custom middleware as Scoped,

```
 public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }
            string AllowSpecifictOrigin = "_allowSpecificOrigins";
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped< YourMiddleware >();
//Add CORS to allow request from specific origin those origins (domain urls) should be added in appsettings as comma separated list here in this case `AllowSpecificOrigin`    
services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(AllowSpecifictOrigin,
                        policy =>
                        {
                            policy.WithOrigins(Configuration["AllowSpecificOrigin"]
                                .Split(','))
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                        });
                });
        }
        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware< YourMiddleware >();
    //Global CORS policy
     app.UseCors(AllowSpecifictOrigin);
    //Incase you allow Cross Origin request to all request instead of above use,
    //app.UseCors(builder => builder
    //.AllowAnyHeader()
    //.AllowAnyMethod()
    //.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
    //.AllowCredentials());
        }
```

appsettings.json will need to have `WithOrigins` settings with list of allowed IP address separated by `,`

```
`WithOrigins : [ "127.0.0.1", "::1" ],
AllowSpecificOrigin : ["https://origin1.com", "http://someother..."]`
```

Comment: I have to support cross-origin too

Comment: I have updated answer with CORS settings with both if your origin as known you can add their domain in config or you can allow to any origin. code is commented  you have to use only one. Do test in your project.